# Send HTML email without user interaction by calling PHP script from iOS Swift 3

Tags: php, ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I recently ran into the problem where I found out that Apple does not allow developers to send an email directly from code without user interaction. This causes some difficulties on my app as I need a code generated email which is in HTML format to be sent from my website server to myself, a third party and the user of the app. I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Is it acceptable to use a PHP script to send the emails for me by calling the script from code?
2. Will doing it this way have my app rejected from app store as I have read that bypassing user interaction in this regard will have the app rejected?
3. There are tons of apps on my iOS device that send emails without me having to interact except for pressing a "submit" button or similar. How are these apps doing it?

Basically, I also need the client to just press a button and 3 emails are sent in HTML format. The client is aware of an email being sent, but I need it in HTML format without the mail client showing up. I have the same app developed on Android and if I cannot have the same flow on Apple devices it kind of breaks look from android to ios. I know this is possible as I have apps on my phone that does it. My question is, are they using PHP scripts? If so, I can do that, but I want to be sure that my app will not be rejected from App Store.

Comment: It only requires user interaction if you are using the built-in mail composer which sends the mail from the user's own email address.  You can have your server send whatever email you want from an email address you control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the API from your webserver for this. If you have for example an API path

```
/mail
```

You can send all the relevant information in as POST paramaters (e.g. "subject" : 'test mail') and from your webserver send the email with a mail function.

This is perfectly acceptable.

You can attach this webserver call to a `UIButton` to make it user-interactable:

```
@IBAction func mailToUser(sender: UIButton) {
    // POST request to /mail with relevant information
}
```